# How can I export api nested array of data into excel file in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I am working on React e-commerce website project and I'm trying to  convert api nested array of data into excel file but I'm facing an issue.

I'm able to get data into the Excel file in react.js but nested array of data is not showing in Excel file?

Anyone can please help me how can I fix it?

I'm using this code for covert data into excel sheet

```js
         productdownloadFile = (datas=this.state.getlist) => {
           const  fileType= "xlsx"
           const ws= XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(datas);
           const wb={Sheets:{data:ws},SheetNames:["data"]};
           const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:"xlsx", type:"array"});
           const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], {type:fileType});
           FileSaver.saveAs(data, "Product_List"+".xlsx")
         }
```

My API data is:

```json
    {
        "success": true,
        "product": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "laptop",
                "description": "this is awesome product,you should byu it",
                "photo": "https://buluckartphoto.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/download%20%283%29.jpeg",
                "lableType": "Veg",
                "status": "0",
                "isTex": "1",
                "GSTrate": 0.23,
                "GSTtyp": "inclusive",
                "HSNcode": "hsn525fgf",
                "videoUpload": "https://buluckartphoto.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/download%20%283%29.jpeg",
                "categoryId": 1,
                "subCategoryId": 1,
                "settingId": 1,
                "createdAt": "2022-05-20T13:26:03.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-05-20T13:26:03.000Z",
                "featureSetting": {
                    "recomendedProduct": true,
                    "deliverySlotStatus": true,
                    "loyaltyProgram": true,
                    "COD": true,
                    "showCOD": false,
                    "reccemendProductNo": 10
                },
                "productphotos": [],
                "varientModels": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "sort": 1,
                        "sku": "htc",
                        "waightunitno": "250 gram",
                        "unit": "gram",
                        "mrp": 1450,
                        "discount": 450,
                        "price": 1000,
                        "stock": 5,
                        "minstock": 1,
                        "outofstock": "continew sell after  thersold"
                    }
                ],
              
                "reccomendProducts": [],
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "vegetable",
                    "photo": "https://buluckartphoto.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/images.jpeg"
                },
                "SubCategory": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "sub_name": "gold star2",
                    "photo": "https://buluckartphoto.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/download.jpeg"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Looking for the same solution